# Deploy Release with older XCode

Tags: xcode, maui

I wanted to deploy my .NET MAUI App built with the latest .NET MAUI version as **Release** on my iPhone compiled with the following MAUI Version:

```xml
<MauiVersion>8.0.7-preview.9929</MauiVersion>
```

Unfortunately, I get the message below that, but only in **Release** and **not in Debug** on the iPhone Simulator 16.2. I am using XCode 14.2 and the Mac is currently not able to upgrade Mac OS to install a newer version of XCode:

```xml
Error   MT4162  The type 'UIKit.UISceneSessionActivationRequest' 
(used as a parameter in UIKit.UIApplication.ActivateSceneSession) 
is not available in iOS 16.2 (it was introduced in iOS 17.0). 
Please build with a newer iOS SDK (usually done by using the most recent
version of Xcode).
```

[image]

Is there any way to deploy it anyway using the current XCode version or upgrade something at least to get it deployed?

Comment: Use Xcodes (with an s) to manage different Xcode versions, downgrade to an older one and use that to build or update your .NET MAUI version

Comment: I have Xcodes with an s installed. But, in my case it is the other way around. I have XCode 14.2 (this an older one) and it says, I should use a newer one (which is e.g. 15.0 or newer for support of iOS 17.0 - see https://developer.apple.com/de/support/xcode/). I can't upgrade my XCode to a newer one as I would need a newer version of Mac OS which I can't install as my MacBook Air is not supported by the newer Mac OS. So, I am looking for a way actually to deploy it anyway - Do you see a possibility for this?

Comment: The other question is why is this only in Release when I try to deploy to my iPhone and not in Debug?

Comment: @GeraldVersluis - I am just thinking, but isn’t this a Bug actually? If this is necessary for a Release Deploy nobody could use 16.2 anymore just newer ones when the used function of the Error message above is not yet available in 16.2 but just from 17.0??

Comment: I’m not sure if I understand your issue 100% correctly. But if you think there is a bug you might want to report it through Visual Studio: go to Help, Provide Feedback and then Report a Problem and provide as much detail as you can

Comment: Okay, I try to describe it in other words: I am working with XCode 14.2 which is compatible with Mac OS Monterey. Monterey is not the most current OS version. If I wanted to update XCode, I would also need to upgrade MacOS. The issue is that MAUI in latest version changed something that prevents the Release-Deploy (not a Debug-Build) and wants me to install the latest XCode. This is not possible for me as my Hardware is not compatible with newer Mac OS versions. Therefore, I can't install XCode in newer a version. But, MAUI is able to compile my Code with XCode 14.2 in Debug - why not Release?

Comment: You can ask for help on GitHub about it. To be honest, VS for Mac is difficult to develop MAUI related things currently.

Comment: I am Working with VS on Windows (17.10 Preview 1). Well, the problem obviously is that they really do not support it anymore. This has a reason: Apple will not support compilations from older Xcode versions from April 29th 2024: https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=fxu2qp7b

Answer (score 0):

Well, according to your comment, as an answer:

As far as the current situation is concerned, it's recommended to use VS for Windows for development. Cause Apple will not support compilations from older Xcode versions from April 29th 2024: [News and Updates](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=fxu2qp7b).

**Update:**

For Xcode, it's best to develop via the latest version 15.

Comment: Well, I would not say this has anything to do with VS for Mac or for Windows. It is just that you can't use older Xcode versions for a deployment to the AppStore. You have to have at least Xcode 15

Comment: Sorry about that, I updated the answer.